# How can I return a variable from a function

Tags: javascript

```
function a (var_a) {
    // do stuff
}
function b () {
    // use the var_a to call function
    a(var_a);
}
```

How can I return the `var_a` when `function a()` is running with the call of `function b()`?

The thing to know is that `var_a` is modified during the run of `function a()`.

Comment: Your question is not showing any type of research you have performed prior to asking the question. Please edit your post if you have researched this already, and what has failed.

Comment: To avoid being down-voted, please read the [ask] section before posting your questions.  Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you need the next level of `var`!

```
var var_d = "Hello World!";

function C (var_c) {

    function a (var_a) {
        // do stuff with var_a
    }
    function b () {
        // use the var_c to call function a
        a(var_c);
    }

    return b();
}

function D () {
    C (var_d);
}
```